# segmentation fault 11 when the first parameter of pthread_create is NULL

Tags: pthreads

This is OK:

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, --omited--);
```

This will cause segmentation fault:

```
pthread_create(NULL, NULL, --omited--);
```

I've checked the manual it didn't say that the first parameter can't be NULL,is it a bug?

I'm on OSX.

Comment: In general, unless the behaviour is documented for what will happen when a parameter *is* `NULL` (or if the parameter is passed through to a callback function that you provide, in which case you control the meaning), you should assume that `NULL` isn't a valid value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_create.html) says that "[u]pon successful completion, *pthread_create*() stores the ID of the created thread in the location referenced by *thread*." Storing a thread ID into a NULL location will cause a segmentation fault.